# Passport js + Express js: allow access to public pages

Tags: express, passport.js

I am working on a web application where I need to allow user to browse around various public pages like login, signup, blog etc. However, to view his account details he needs to login. I am using passport js for authentication. This is an express js application.

I am using a middleware interrupt in express to check if the user is logged in to render the appropriate pages like this:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {

      if(req.isAuthenticated()) {
        next();
      } else {
        res.render('partials/unauth');
      }
   })
```

Basically, here I am saying if the user is logged in render any page that the user is requesting else show him a page which says : Unauthorized or Page does not exist.

But, I want to add a few exceptions to the rules, saying that if the req is partials/blog (which is a public page not requiring login), show the blog page. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

It might be late now, but I did manage to solve this a few months back with the below approach:

```
var publicPages = ['signup', 'login', 'error', 'forgotpassword', 'unauth', '404'];
var privatePages = ['dashboard', 'account'];
//name is the page requested
if(publicPages.indexOf(name)!=-1 || privatePages.indexOf(name)!=-1 && req.isAuthenticated()) {
  res.render('partials/'+name);
} else if(publicPages.indexOf(name)==-1 && privatePages.indexOf(name)==-1) {
  res.render('partials/404')
} else {
  res.render('partials/unauth');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create middleware: `authenticatedOrGuest.js`

```js
const passport = require('passport');

module.exports = function (req, res, next) {
  // in this sample used jwt strategy, but you can use any
  return passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }, function (err, user) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    if (user) req.user = user;
    next();
  })(req, res, next);
};
```

And then use it in app routes: `app.js`

```js
const authenticatedOrGuest = require('./middleware/authenticatedOrGuest.js');

app.get('/my-api-endpoint', authenticatedOrGuest, function(req, res) {
  let message;
  if(req.user) {
    // here logic for authenticated user
    message = 'Authenticated!';
  } else {
    // here logic for guest
    message = 'Guest!';
  }
  res.send(message);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You should keep this authentication code inside a function like:

```
function isLoggedIn(req, res, next){
      if(req.isAuthenticated()) {
        return next();
      } else {
        res.render('partials/unauth');
      }
};
```

And say you want the user to be logged in when a route is hit then you should pass this function as a parameter to the route.

```
app.get('/viewDetails', isLoggedIn, function(req, res){
});
```

If you don't care if the user is logged in or not, then you should not pass this function as a parameter to the route.

```
app.get('/blog', function(req, res){
});
```

Comment: Hmm... I am aware of this approach. But, was thinking that this approach has higher error probability as I may forget to use isLoggedIn function for a private page. As the number of public pages are lower I was thinking if it would be much easier to keep this in the middleware.